# Найти пиццу по ширине. Как найти по нескольким размерам сразу?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Найти пиццу по ширине

```
[['Четыре сыра','30','900'],
 ['Гавайская','25','1000'],
 ['Пепперони','20','1000'],
 ['Мексиканская','20','800'],
 ['Маргарита','15','750']]
```

Например: 30, 15

```
[['Четыре сыра','30','900'],
 ['Маргарита','15','750']]
```

Как найти по нескольким размерам сразу?

```
Pizza = [['Четыре сыра', '30', '900'],
 ['Гавайская', '25', '1000'],
 ['Пепперони', '20', '1000'],
 ['Мексиканская', '20', '800'],
 ['Маргарита', '15', '750']]

Pizza_size = str(input())

for i in Pizza:
    if i[1] == Pizza_size:
        print(i)
```

Comment: И правильно искать по str, если в списке только цифры?

Answer (score 2):

Можно добавить обработку введенного размера, чтобы получить список размеров, после при переборе пицц, проверить входит ли размер в заданный список размеров

*После тестирования алгоритма, оставите `pizza_size = input()`, чтобы задавать извне*

```
Pizza = [
    ['Четыре сыра', '30', '900'],
    ['Гавайская', '25', '1000'],
    ['Пепперони', '20', '1000'],
    ['Мексиканская', '20', '800'],
    ['Маргарита', '15', '750']
]

pizza_size = '30, 15'
# pizza_size = input()
need_sizes = pizza_size.strip().replace(' ', '').split(',')
# ['30', '15']

for x in Pizza:
    if x[1] in need_sizes:
        print(x)
```

Результат:

```
['Четыре сыра', '30', '900']
['Маргарита', '15', '750']
```

Answer (score 0):

Так как в один прекрасный день вы захотите выводить пиццы больше\меньше определенного размера, то лучше сразу преобразовать строки в числа.

```py
pizzas = [
    ['Четыре сыра', '30', '900'],
    ['Гавайская', '25', '1000'],
    ['Пепперони', '20', '1000'],
    ['Мексиканская', '20', '800'],
    ['Маргарита', '15', '750']
]

pizzas = [[x[0], int(x[1]), int(x[2])] for x in pizzas]

pizza_sizes = '20 25' # input()
pizza_sizes = [int(x) for x in pizza_sizes.split()]

print(*filter(lambda x: x[1] in pizza_sizes, pizzas))
# ['Гавайская', 25, 1000] ['Пепперони', 20, 1000] ['Мексиканская', 20, 800]
```